# java.text.simpledateformat behaving differently in an Android project than in java SE 1.8

Tags: java, android, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I was parsing date strings using Spanish Locale with `SimpleDateFormat` in an Android project and for some strange reason I was getting `ParseException` only with dates that had September as a month. Not knowing why this behaviour took place, I decided to create a toy program in Eclipse with a date string that was throwing this exception, in order to reproduce this bug. To my surprise, no exception was thrown and the date was parsed correctly.

So my question is: why does the first block of code (with jdk 1.8_25) does not throw a `ParseException`, while the second block of code (in an empty Android Studio application, with SDK 21 rev.2 and Build-Tools 21.1.2) throws a `ParseException`? Can anyone else reproduce this strange behaviour? What am I doing wrong? Shouldn't in both cases the strings be parsed correctly as dates?

**Code #1 (jdk 1.8_25)**:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
private static final String THIS_YEAR_TIME_FORMAT = "d 'de' MMM, HH:mm";
private static final DateFormat THIS_YEAR_TIME_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat(THIS_YEAR_TIME_FORMAT,
        new Locale("es", "ES"));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String problemStr = "3 de sep, 22:50";
    Date time;
    try {
        time = THIS_YEAR_TIME_FORMATTER.parse(problemStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

**Code #2 (Android SDK 21 rev.2, Build-Tools 21.1.2)**:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final String THIS_YEAR_TIME_FORMAT = "d 'de' MMM, HH:mm";
private static final DateFormat THIS_YEAR_TIME_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat(THIS_YEAR_TIME_FORMAT,
        new Locale("es", "ES"));

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final String problemStr = "3 de sep, 22:50";
    Date time;
    try {
        time = THIS_YEAR_TIME_FORMATTER.parse(problemStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like "*sept.*" is the proper Spanish September/septiembre abbreviation according to [CLDR](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/26/by_type/date_&_time.gregorian.html), which Android uses. For Java, CLDR support is only added in [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.8.html) and is not used by default, Java default implementation is not 100% compatible with that of CLDR, guess this is one of the incompatibilities.

<s>Looks like it's a major bug in Android 5.0+...</s>

The code works on Galaxy S3 (Android 4.3) & Android 4.4 emulator, but fails on both Android 5.0 emulator and Nexus 7 (2013) running 5.0.1. Even using a `Locale` instance returned by `Locale.getAvailableLocales()` would fail on Android 5.0.x.

Google giveth and Google taketh away, I guess.

Comment: Thank you for investigating this. How did you find out about this? // I want 'sep' to be parsed to September always, not 'sept.'. How can I ensure this with `SimpleDateFormat` so that it works everywhere?

Comment: @hallaplay835 It took quite a bit of googling and reading, CLDR certainly doesn't make their data easily comprehensible. As for making it work everywhere, one way is to catch `ParseException` and replace "sep" with "sept." from the String and try again. It's an ugly solution, but I haven't seen any documentation on how to achieve this in a better way.